# Jquery won't let me select value of td, when iterating over tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would like to select the value of a td, when the row contains a checked checkbox. I'm able to select the rows which hold a checked checkbox but I can't iterate over the row to select the key.

This is the table structure.

```
<table class="test"><thead><tr>
<th class="table-header-name">select</th>
<th class="placeholder" style="min-width:100px"></th>
<th class="table-header-name">Key</th>
<th class="table-header-name">hash</th>
<th class="table-header-name">type</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="table-body">
<tr class="table-row">
<td><input class="change-select" type="checkbox"></td>
<td class="placeholder"></td>
<td class="key">TICKET:44433</td>
<td class="hash">444nhh</td>
<td class="type">COOL</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The value I'm looking for is the text inside the td-tag of class "key".

```
<td class="key">TICKET:44433</td>
```

First I'm selecting the rows which hold a checked checkbox:

```
 AJS.$('.test tr :has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function (i,val) {
                console.log("this no:"+i+": " + val);
                // get td of class "key" and print the value

                })

            });
```

well, I tried lots of ways to get the value of the td, like:

```
this.find("td .key").text();
this.find("td").eq([number])
```

It will return nothing in both cases.

I figured out that I'm iterating over `HTMLTableCellElements`, when I'm using `'.aui tr :has(:checkbox:checked)'`, but in this related topic it should work: [Jquery Selecting Table Rows with Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430254/jquery-selecting-table-rows-with-checkbox)

```
  console.log("find td: " + AJS.$(this).find('td'));
                AJS.$(this).find('td').each(function(key,element){
                    console.log('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);
                })
```

Will generate the following output:

```
"find td: [object Object]"
```

thats it...

So I guess there must be something wrong with the way I'm selecting the row. I hope you can give me a hint here.

Comment: You are getting `[object Object]` from your log statement, because you are using string concatenation in there – don’t do that, always log objects in their “native” form, without concatenating them with something else. That way, you will get an actual object that you can inspect for content logged to console, and not just its string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.change-select').attr('checked') == 'checked'){
        alert($(this).find('.key').text());
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6x46b50/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` once you get down to the row with a checkbox checked:

```
$('.table-row:has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function (idx, comp){
        console.log($(comp).find('.key')[0].innerText);
        //console.log(comp);
    });
```

[Here is an fiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/69gw9o38/)