# Getting data from a specific column in a HTML table when a checkbox in that row is checked using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a HTML table with 5 columns. The first column is a checkbox. I want to find the content of the 5th column (last column) when the checkbox in that row is checked.

**HTML :**

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</tr>
      <th>B</tr>
      <th>C</tr>
      <th>D</tr>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class="chk" /></td>
      <td>data for A1</td>
      <td>data for B1</td>
      <td>data for C1</td>
      <td>data for D1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class="chk"/></td>
      <td>data for A2</td>
      <td>data for B2</td>
      <td>data for C2</td>
      <td>data for D2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

I am a beginner in javascript but have tried doing this.

**JS : **

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if($('input.chk').is(':checked')){
         var y = $("td:nth-of-type(5)").html();
         alert(y);
         }
      });
```

This function returns only for the first row i.e when the checkbox is checked it shows "data for D1". But I want it for all the rows.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430254/jquery-selecting-table-rows-with-checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one

```
$(document).on('click','input.chk',function(){
    // getting the tds with in the rows in which check exists 
    $tds=$(this).parent().siblings();

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      $data=$($tds[$tds.length-1]).text();
      alert($data);
    }

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once:

```
$(".chk").on("change", function(){
  var y = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(4).html();
  alert(y);
});//
```

You can add `:checked` condition if you want to execute this code only if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is based on using [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```js
$(function () {
  $(':checkbox').on('click', function(e) {
    if (this.checked == true) {
      var fifthEle = $(this).parent().siblings().eq(3);
      $('#logMsg').append('<p>' + fifthEle.text() + '</p>');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A
        <th>B
        <th>C
        <th>D
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class="chk"/></td>
        <td>data for A1</td>
        <td>data for B1</td>
        <td>data for C1</td>
        <td>data for D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class="chk"/></td>
        <td>data for A2</td>
        <td>data for B2</td>
        <td>data for C2</td>
        <td>data for D2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="logMsg"></div>
```